# Xcode fails to archive project

Tags: ios, xcode4

When I try to archive my iOS App, I get a failed message without any issues. As seen on screen below *(edit: had to remove the image because of low reputation. It just shows Xcode with failed in tool bar and the empty issues sidebar)*.

There are no underlines, spaces or anything like this in my bundle identifier. Also I didn't import any files by a wrong extension. Like mentioned in another question.
When I try to run it in a simulator, everything runs fine.

Any ideas? The project is quite large, and I'm not skilled enough to reuse everything in a new project.

Comment: Hi, blender, you can always leave the image URL and somebody will make it displayed for you. Can you check the console output (Applciations > Utils > Console) ?

Comment: [link](http://euve22325.vserver.de/xcode-screen.png)
the console doesnt show up even one line about this. Tried to refresh as well.

Comment: Can be closed. My fault was to remove an deprecated provisioning file and import a new one with the needed testerdevices. Had to update the Code Signing Identity as well. Anyway... thanks for removing literals.

Comment: Or can be answered by yourself :)

Comment: Blender, please post the solution as an answer and mark it accepted. This will help future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. I deleted the old provisioning file and imported an updated one (with just more devices). XCode just did not recognize the new provisioning file and i had to change the Setting "Code Signing Identity" once more.
Couldn't answer yesterday. Because of my reputations as well xD